# SFTP Error not capturing

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, sftp

```
sftp  xx@xx.xx.xx.xx:/DIR/ <<< $'put /transfer/dr**' && echo "Passed - `date`" 1>>$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILEerr
```

Can you please help me  what's  missing in above  command.
Issue  is, it's not  throwing any error message even though SFTP  failed to put.

Comment: You're not quoting variables and you are using backticks.  Also the stuff after `&&` will only be executed _if_ there is **no** error.  You probably want to separate commands with `;` instead.  However that still wouldn't work,  you are only redirecting stderr from your echo command which likely wont have any errors.

Comment: What is `$'put /transfer/dr**'`  supposed to expand to?

Comment: @Jesse_b It's a Bash "C-string", but the `$` is not needed at all in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `&&` to chain the commands together; if the sftp command succeeds, you'll execute the `echo` command. If the sftp command fails you *won't* execute the `echo` command. Perhaps you could split the command more clearly:

```
if sftp xx@xx.xx.xx.xx:/DIR/ <<< $'put /transfer/dr**'
then
  echo "Passed - `date`" 1>>$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILEerr
else
  echo "Failed ..."
fi
```